# What account is my service running as?

Tags: .net, windows-services

How do I determine what account a service is running as from within the service itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A language would have been useful..

In C++:
[GetUserName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724432(VS.85).aspx)

C#

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();
```

Comment: Strange. I could have sworn I tried that before, but this time it seems to be working perfectly.