# Find which account a service is set to "Log On As"

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

How to find out the user account ([Local System/User etc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceaccount.aspx)) a service is set to run under ("Log On As")?

Unlike this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404144/what-account-is-my-service-running-as) this code can't run from within the service itself and the service may not be running.

The [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx) class has useful methods for getting the status but not the "Log On As" user.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is the only way I know of, I found it looking around and tested it, it works. Make sure you use the Service Name not it's Display Name, you will also need to add a reference to **System.Management**

```
string serviceName = "aspnet_state";

SelectQuery query = new System.Management.SelectQuery(string.Format(
    "select name, startname from Win32_Service where name = '{0}'", serviceName));
using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
    new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(query))
{
    foreach (ManagementObject service in searcher.Get())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format(
            "Name: {0} - Logon : {1} ", service["Name"], service["startname"]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using WMI and the `Win32_Service` class with the `StartName` parameter?

[This article](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial225_Listing-Services-with-Csharp.html) might help.

Answer (score 1):

This will do your Job

```
 Get-WMIObject Win32_Service | Where-Object {$_.startname -ne "localSystem" }| Where-Object {$_.startname -ne "NT AUTHORITY\LocalService" } |Where-Object {$_.startname -ne "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService" } |select startname, name
```